# check constraint for date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need a check constraint for date so no data can be entered after today's/this date.

please advise thanks all

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable
ADD CONSTRAINT yourDateTimeColumn CHECK (yourDateTimeColumn < GetDate() );
```

Comment: do i just add this in the expression part of check constraint ?

Comment: I think your logic is the opposite of what the OP wants: you're CHECKing that the datetime value is in the future, I think the OP wants to make sure the values are in the past. But without more information (data types, version of SQL Server, is the time relevant or only the date etc.) it's not possible to give a definite answer anyway.

Comment: If you run the code in the analizer it add directly the constraint.

Comment: this error came up Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "EventDate". The conflict occurred in database "S00103684", table "dbo.event_tbl", column 'EventDate'.

Comment: Martin, actually have you got any record with a Date greater than today?

Answer (score 3):

To remove the time part on SQL Server 2008, use `cast...date`

Also, I assume you can have dates *including* today

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable
ADD CONSTRAINT yourDateTimeColumn CHECK (
    CAST(yourDateTimeColumn as date) <= CAST(GETDATE() as date)
     );
```