# Check Constraint on Date of Birth column to check if person is age 18 or over

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

New to SQL Server and need help with check constraint.

How can I create a check constraint on DateOfBirth column to only allow date of birth which is age 18 or greater?  Example of current syntax:

```
Create Table Member (
    Memberid Int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Title Varchar(10),
    Firstname Varchar(40),
    Lastname Varchar(40),
    DateOfBirth Date Not Null
);
```

Comment: You might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938523/check-constraint-for-date

Answer (score 0):

Try this one mate!

```
create table person (DateOfBirth date check (DATEDIFF(year,DateOfBirth,getdate()) > 18))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one Mate, It'll allow those who are 18 or above only

```
create table person (DateOfBirth date 
            Check(DATEADD(year,-18,GETDATE()) >= DateOfBirth ))
```